# Infinite long polling using Javascript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, polling

I am trying to make a long polling client that keeps polling an API indefinitely. It's pretty straight forward while using python due to its synchronous nature but in javascript, the loop doesn't wait for the post request to complete before sending new requests. Further research showed that I shouldn't use loops and should rather use a recursive function.

Here is the simplified javascript code but I am afraid it's going to produce the error "maximum call stack size exceeded" eventually.

```
function collect(date) {
    needle('post', url, pollData, { json: true, response_timeout: 60000 })
        .then(response => {
            try {
                console.log(response.body.toSTring())
                collect()
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(`Response Code: ${response.statusCode}, ${error.message}`)
                collect()
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message)
            collect()
        })
}

collect()
```

Can someone please guide me a proper way to achieve infinite long polling without producing an error? Thanks

Comment: If your project permits it, consider using websockets instead of polling.

Comment: As written, this is a disaster in error situations as it will completely hammer the target server as fast as possible if you ever get an error back from the needle promise.  Retries after error should have an exponential backoff.  Wait for some period of time, retry, wait for some period of time, retry, increase period of time you wait for, retry, etc...

Comment: This will not produce maximum stack size error because you are calling `needle()` from within a `.then()` or `.catch()` handler which both unwind the stack before they call their registered callbacks.

Comment: Your logic would likely be simpler with `await`.

Comment: @Filipe Zavan, My project is to get data from an API and the API only accepts HTTP post requests.

Comment: @jfriend00, I will definitely add the logic to wait for a certain period of time before retrying in the case of error. I am just trying to find the best way to do long polling and this is the best I have come up so far. There is so much talk about how long polling works but very little code examples to show how to make it work.

Comment: That may be because long polling is fairly outdated.  Many use webSockets or Server Sent Events now so the server can "push" data to the client.

Comment: Instead of calling `collect` directly and causing the stack size exceeded error, use `setTimeout` like so: `setTimeout(collect, 0);`